# Проверка процессов в цикле while

Tags: c#, консоль

Есть 2 процесса игры которые я хочу чекать на запуск:

```
var GameProcess = new[] { "PB", "PointBlank" };
```

Как мне проверить их в цикле `while`?

Затем в консоли я делаю себе таймер в котором запускаю определённый метод (класс) который что-то делает.

```
private static void TimerCallback(object o)
{        
   Game.Clean(); // чистка файлов.
}

public static Timer MyTimer;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
   MyTimer = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, 5000);
}

private static bool CheckProcessExists()
{
  var GameProcess = new[] { "PointBlank", "PB" };
  while (true)
  {
     foreach (string myListLine in GameProcess)
     {
       if (Process.GetProcessesByName(myListLine).Length > 0)

      // Console.Write("проверка запуска игры..");
      // Если процесс не существует то продолжать сканировать 
     // Но тут проблема в том что вывод на консоль будет 
     // очень много повторяться.
     // Хотелось бы как-то так: (Console)

        проверка запуска игры..  
        игра найдена запускаем таймер  
        выполняется метод  Game.Clean();

        (Выход из игры)

        Остановка таймера...
        проверка запуска игры.. 

     }
  }
}
```

Не могу сделать логику к программе:

1 - Сделать бесконечный цикл проверки процесса ( без торможения программы)

2 - Если процесс есть, запустить метод из `TimerCallback`

3 - Остановить таймер если процесс не обнаружен || если он есть запустить таймер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Ты можешь добавить незначительную задержку внутрь своего while (true) при помощи [`Thread.Sleep`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/d00bd51t(v=vs.110).aspx), например в 1000 мс. На самом деле правильнее добавить [`ManualResetEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx), который будет взводиться при прерывании программы (н.п. Ctrl+C в консольном приложении).
2. Дождавшись процесса, ты выходишь из цикла и в этом месте создаёшь свой таймер.
3. У экземпляра найденного процесса есть метода [`WaitForExit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/fb4aw7b8(v=vs.110).aspx), используй его для того чтобы дождаться завершения процесса, после чего освобди таймер вызовом `Dispose`. Опять же в данном случае правильнее добавить [`AutoResetEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.autoresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx), который будет сбрасываться при начале выполнения коллбека таймера и выставляться после, по его наличию или отсутствию ты можешь пропускать новые итерации таймера, если предыдущая ещё не завершилась (мало ли), а также дождаться завершения выполнения последней итерации перед выходом.

P.S. Не забудь обернуть обработчик события в блок `try-catch`, так как любая ошибка в процессе его выполнения приведёт к падению приложения с необработанным исключением.

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ)